# Convert array of lists to table

Tags: json, r

I have a json data file that contains data that I want to work with. It looks something like that:

```
[
{"key1":1,"key2":2,"key3":[123],"key4":{"345":1}},
{"key1":2,"key2":4,"key3":[246],"key4":{"980":2},"key5":50}
]
```

I used packages rjson and RJSONIO (so far, they gave identical results) to read it, here's what I got:

```
> json_file = "~/Documents/test.json"
> test_json = fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file, warn = FALSE), collapse = ""))
> test_json
[[1]]
[[1]]$key1
[1] 1

[[1]]$key2
[1] 2

[[1]]$key3
[1] 123

[[1]]$key4
345 
  1 


[[2]]
[[2]]$key1
[1] 2

[[2]]$key2
[1] 4

[[2]]$key3
[1] 246

[[2]]$key4
980 
  2 

[[2]]$key5
[1] 50

> summary(test_json)
     Length Class  Mode
[1,] 4      -none- list
[2,] 5      -none- list
```

So, if I understand this correctly, I got an array of lists. But since this arrays obviously have the same keys, I want to convert it to a table instead — so that I can do things like test_json$key1. How can I achieve this?

(I hope that it's clear what I'm trying to do, I'm very new to R and don't know all the correct terms for things. I also don't imply to ask you to do this work for me, but I suspect that there could be a built-in function for situations like that, or if there isn't, just advice on in what direction I should move would be nice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you have is a list of lists. (Arrays in R are multidimensional matrices.) And tables actually mean something specific as well (see `?table`). What you probably want is a *data frame*.

As a first step, try:

```
lapply(test_json,as.data.frame)
[[1]]
  key1 key2 key3 X345
1    1    2  123    1

[[2]]
  key1 key2 key3 X980 key5
1    2    4  246    2   50
```

which will give you a list of data frames. But at this point you have a small problem. The data frames each have different numbers of columns. If they all had the same columns, we could simply do:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(test_json,as.data.frame))
```

and you'd get one big data frame back. As an alternative, you could use `rbind.fill` from the **plyr** package:

```
do.call(rbind.fill,lapply(test_json,as.data.frame))
  key1 key2 key3 X345 X980 key5
1    1    2  123    1   NA   NA
2    2    4  246   NA    2   50
```

which will fill missing values with NA as needed.

I should add that something went kind of wonky when I tried to read you example in using **rjson**. I'm not sure why (**edit** Yup, tried with **RJSONIO** and it matched your output. Apparently they *do* differ occasionally.), but my answer should still apply, even though I ended up with some garbled columns.

Comment: Thanks, it looks exactly like what I wanted! The only difference is that I found the function smartbind from gtools package to be better suited for my needs.